# Simple example of genetic alg minimization

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I have been looking for a while for examples of how I could find the points at which a function achieves its minimum using a genetic algorithm approach in Python. I looked at  DEAP documentation, but the examples there were pretty hard for me to follow. For example:

```
def  function(x,y):
     return x*y+3*x-x**2
```

I  am looking  for some references on how  I can make a genetic algorithm in which I can feed some initial random values for both x and y (not coming from the same dimensions). Can someone with experience creating and using genetic algorithms give me some guidance on this?

Comment: This problem is solvable analytically using calculus and does not require statistical learning. Assuming you want a numerical solution, its more readily solvable using stochastic gradient descent rather than a genetic algorithm.  Also, notice that you have defined a function that is linear in y and the x term that scales fastest goes like -x^2, so for most parameter regimes, the solution is uninteresting (xmax,ymin).  I suggest spending a little more time finding an example that is more meaningful and deciding between SGD and GA. [Here's a true genetic algorithm example](http://boxcar2d.com/)

Comment: Hi , in fact it is  just  an  example. In practice  my function is a combination of 2  nested  functions in which  I  dont even have a hessian.

Comment: But do you see the relation between stochastic gradient descent and genetic algorithms?  And that the example you provided is so simplistic that there is no difference between the two? All I'm getting at is that you need a more complex example to illicit the differences and hence better understand the latter.

Comment: I was looking  for an example where it is described a trivial example like the one aboce in order to   generalize from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a trivial example](http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/), which captures the essence of genetic algorithms more meaningfully than the polynomial you provided.  The polynomial you provided is solvable via [`stochastic gradient descent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), which is a simpler minimimization technique.  For this reason, I am instead suggesting this excellent article and example by Will Larson.

[Quoted from the original article](http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/):

> **Defining a Problem to Optimize** Now we're going to put together a simple example of using a genetic algorithm in Python. We're going to
>   optimize a very simple problem: trying to create a list of N numbers
>   that equal X when summed together.
>
> If we set N = 5 and X = 200, then these would all be appropriate
>   solutions.
>
> ```
> lst = [40,40,40,40,40]
> lst = [50,50,50,25,25]
> lst = [200,0,0,0,0]
> ```

Take a look at the [entire article](http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/), but here is the **complete code**:

> ```
> # Example usage
> from genetic import *
> target = 371
> p_count = 100
> i_length = 6
> i_min = 0
> i_max = 100
> p = population(p_count, i_length, i_min, i_max)
> fitness_history = [grade(p, target),]
> for i in xrange(100):
>     p = evolve(p, target)
>     fitness_history.append(grade(p, target))
>
> for datum in fitness_history:
>    print datum
> """
> from random import randint, random
> from operator import add
>
> def individual(length, min, max):
>     'Create a member of the population.'
>     return [ randint(min,max) for x in xrange(length) ]
>
> def population(count, length, min, max):
>     """
>     Create a number of individuals (i.e. a population).
>
>     count: the number of individuals in the population
>     length: the number of values per individual
>     min: the minimum possible value in an individual's list of values
>     max: the maximum possible value in an individual's list of values
>
>     """
>     return [ individual(length, min, max) for x in xrange(count) ]
>
> def fitness(individual, target):
>     """
>     Determine the fitness of an individual. Higher is better.
>
>     individual: the individual to evaluate
>     target: the target number individuals are aiming for
>     """
>     sum = reduce(add, individual, 0)
>     return abs(target-sum)
>
> def grade(pop, target):
>     'Find average fitness for a population.'
>     summed = reduce(add, (fitness(x, target) for x in pop))
>     return summed / (len(pop) * 1.0)
>
> def evolve(pop, target, retain=0.2, random_select=0.05, mutate=0.01):
>     graded = [ (fitness(x, target), x) for x in pop]
>     graded = [ x[1] for x in sorted(graded)]
>     retain_length = int(len(graded)*retain)
>     parents = graded[:retain_length]
>     # randomly add other individuals to
>     # promote genetic diversity
>     for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
>         if random_select > random():
>             parents.append(individual)
>     # mutate some individuals
>     for individual in parents:
>         if mutate > random():
>             pos_to_mutate = randint(0, len(individual)-1)
>             # this mutation is not ideal, because it
>             # restricts the range of possible values,
>             # but the function is unaware of the min/max
>             # values used to create the individuals,
>             individual[pos_to_mutate] = randint(
>                 min(individual), max(individual))
>     # crossover parents to create children
>     parents_length = len(parents)
>     desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
>     children = []
>     while len(children) < desired_length:
>         male = randint(0, parents_length-1)
>         female = randint(0, parents_length-1)
>         if male != female:
>             male = parents[male]
>             female = parents[female]
>             half = len(male) / 2
>             child = male[:half] + female[half:]
>             children.append(child)
>     parents.extend(children)
>     return parents
> ```

I think it could be quite pedagogically useful to also solve your original problem using this algorithm and then also construct a solution using `stochastic grid search` or `stochastic gradient descent` and you will gain a deep understanding of the juxtaposition of those three algorithms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How is SGD a subset of Genetic Algorithms? SGD isn't population-based, doesn't use any of the genetic operators, and genetic algorithms do not use gradient-based optimization.

Comment: Hi ANSU5 , excelent   reference , just wait to  put it in pracitce tommorow

Comment: @Jérémie Clos, you are correct. I have edited the answer to reflect this.  I was caught up in the discussion above and was trying to illustrate some similarities in various optimization techniques.  But this likely obfuscated more than in elucidated.